Capture vertical scroll wheel in Vim to "break out" of Vim terminal
I often use a Vim Terminal in a lower window in my daily driver setup. In Neovim, if I initiate a mouse scroll wheel event while in the Neovim Terminal, it stops the running Terminal and allows me to scroll through my Terminal screen.
As it stands now in my Vim setup, I have to <C-Leader><C-n> to stop the terminal every time I want to scroll through the terminal history or move to a new window.
How would I be able to:

Capture a vertical mouse wheel event
See if cursor is in a Terminal
If so, execute <C-Leader><C-n>

?
Thanks
